# Adding Image to TextView Affects Text's Centering in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple `LinearLayout` with a  `TextView` whose text I would like centered.  The problem is, when I add an image to it with `android:drawableRight`, it affects the centering of the text (moving it to the left).

### From my layout:

```
TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBeltpack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="55-3"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_battery_90_black" />
```

I'm able to add `android:paddingLeft` to force the text to be centered, but I'm sure there is a better way.

How can I force the text to be centered, irrespective of the image contained in the `TextView`?

Comment: You can center the TextView without image in a RelativeLayout and add a ImageView with the image on the right of the TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profilePic"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mohit Verma"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

and make sure that LinearLayout is having   `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBzQl.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what I asked.  Look at your Result Image.  Do you see how the name is pushed to the left of center?  That's because you added the graphic.  If you were to remove the graphic, the name would then be centered correctly.

Comment: I've added `android: drawablePadding =" 10dp "`. That's why it is little left of the center. Otherwise, it is perfectly aligned in the center.

Comment: OK, I see that now, but what is different between yours and mine then?  I see you're using `android:drawableEnd` instead of `android:drawableRight`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: What is the actual result you want?

Comment: as I stated in the original question, using `drawableRight` to add an image along with the text moves the text away from center (in this case, it moves the text to the left).  I want the text to be centered horizontally within the screen even though I've added a graphic to the right.  Right now, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Post your complete layout file.